# MySQL database schema for shipping routes, avoiding complexity

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, nosql

I'm trying to build a MySQL schema for the following situation.

A book is being delivered from a **locationA** to **locationB**, through several other locations. *e.g.* For a book delivered from Vancouver to Los Angeles, we can go from Vancouver to Seattle to Portland to Los Angeles (Route 1), or alternatively it can take a different route from Vancouver to Calgary to Blaine to Seattle to Los Angeles (Route 2).

For every book delivered

- I'd like to keep track of the locations it passed through.
- I'd like    to keep track of whether the book arrived at each
  location "on-time"    or "late".

Later, when I pull up information about a given book, it's going to show the shipping route it took. Similarly, I'd be able to pull up books that were shipped through Calgary (or any other location). Also, I'd be able to show alternative shipping routes that were taken by multiple copies of the same book.

Already, a MySQL schema for this is beginning to sound very convoluted. I understand that with the proper use of foreign-keys and join-operations, we can make something work out.

However, I'm wondering whether the community can recommend a better way to organize this information. Is MySQL well-suited for this job? Should I just try to store this information on external XML files? Or should I explore a NoSQL approach? Comments would be very welcome.

Comment: This is a little OT for SO. Maybe try the dba forum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for noSql solution document structure/schema could look like:

```
{
  _id:shippingIdHere,
  book:{document containing book data}
  routeInfo:[ {cityId(or just name), timeStamp, isOnTime}]
}
```

The document will contain an array of route info data - city, time, and indicator of on time route.
Then there will be a  need to add an index on routeInfo fields to get what's needed faster.

I see no issues with MySQL as this can be done by creating a table like this

> rowID|shipingId|bookId|cityId|isOnTime|timeStamp

and making a view will do the job.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this nosql schema will only work efficiently on a DBMS supporting multiple indexes per collection (otherwise you need multiple collections). And XML is a complete non-starter.